# Singular and plural form in a section title

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number, headlinese

This is a quick short question, but it hinders me every time when I write a section title. For example, if I want to use a single word 'question' as a section title, should I use it in a singular form ('question') or in a plural form ('questions')? I assume the same rule goes for every other case.

PS. The supposed 'question(s)' section will contain a number of questions.

Comment: If you have more than onequestion then I do not understand why you think that you have to use the singular form for plural. Please, explain your doubt:)

Comment: Oh, I just had the doubt because I have heard that we don't use articles in section titles, such as 'Number of items' instead of 'The number of items', for the sake of simplicity. I thought this rule could go for the singular/plural form. :)

Comment: There is no "rule" that prevents the use of the articles in a chapter or section title. Titles should be descriptive; if there are multiple questions in a section, _Questions_ (or _Some Questions_ or _The Questions_) will serve perfectly well as a title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a form, the title of a section containing multiple questions will generally have this format:

> → Questions
>
> → Questions concerning/about [noun phrase]
>   
> <sub>e.g. Questions concerning duration of residence</sub>
>
> → [noun phrase] questions
>   
> <sub>e.g. Homeownership questions</sub>

In a book or academic paper, you might use a determiner and/or an adjective:

> → Some questions concerning/about [noun phrase]
>   
> <sub>e.g. Some questions about the status of pronouns</sub>
>
> → A few more difficult questions

This would be seen as somewhat more conversational and prosaic, rather than official and formulaic.

Note that a playful website might also have something along those more conversational lines:

> → A few quick questions about your background

Answer (score 1):

If there is just one question, it is normal to just put a short form of the question in the section title.

If there is more than one question, Luke has three good suggestions:

- Questions
- <Topic> questions
- Questions about <topic>

Some writing style guides suggest using "Sentence case" in section titles.  Other writing style guides suggest using "Title Case" in section titles.

Comment: Some academic journals strongly discourage putting questions in section titles.  Instead, they encourage putting brief answers in section titles.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the title whichever name you want, however, notice that depending on the name you give the reader will think different.

You can, for instance, give such a name:

- Questions
- The questions
- A whole lot of questions
- A number of questions
- Certain questions
- Many questions

Or some other way.

Edit:

- A saucerful of questions
- A pocketful of questions.

Comment: "A question and a question more" is ungrammatical today (it could mean "a question and another question" very archaically), and the rest of these are not suitable for a section title except "Questions".

Comment: @LukeSawczak An author can give whichever name they want, it's for them to decide. There's no wrong or right.

Comment: No argument here, but if a person's asking what people generally do and what would be expected in their own writing, I would rather cite standard usage. Of course you can fancifully title a section "Some things I've been wondering lately" (or your "saucerful" and "pocketful") or whatever else if the mood strikes you. :) That's why I tried to indicate the genre for the different wordings in my answer.

Comment: @LukeSawczak By throwing such standards you corner the guy, yet, I agree, this is what most would do, however, it's okay not to be like others.